# Is it possible to query multiple document sub-collections in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, database-design, google-cloud-firestore

I'm planning the structure of my DB for a project using Cloud Firestore, and I'm currently trying to figure out the best approach to storing data and associating it to users. The specifics are as follows:

I have a collection of user documents at the root of my DB, and I want users to be able to make posts that are accessible both by looking at a user profile page which displays posts by that user, and in aggregate by looking at a page displaying posts by all users.

Storing a user's posts in a sub-collection of the user document would make it very easy to fetch a user's posts for their profile, but is it possible to write an elegant query that merges every user's post sub-collections into one result set?

Or would a better approach to be to have another collection in the root of my called posts, and have a field on each post containing the user's UID or a denormalized copy of the user document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A query runs against a single document collection. There is (currently) no way to query across multiple (sub)collections.

That means you'll probably want to keep the user documents in a top-level `documents` collection, with a `owner` property for their UIDs. Then you can select a user's post with a simple `documentsRef.where("owner", "==", uid)`.

Comment: This is now possible with collection group queries. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46573167/6253640 for more details.