# Firestore - subcollection query for a specific document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

***Note: Querying across subcollections is not currently supported in Cloud Firestore. If you need to query data across collections, use root-level collections.***

When I read the documentation for me it's not clear if it's possible to do something like this:

```
var listsRef = db.collection("users/user1/lists");
var query = listsRef.where("public", "==", true);
```

I can understand that it's not supported if I try to do this:

```
var listsRef = db.collection("users/{userId}/lists");
var query = listsRef.where("public", "==", true);
```

But I am wondering if I can query in a specific collection that comes from a specific document. In fact, what's the difference here and in a root collection?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first snippet executes a query against the `lists` subcollection of the `user1` document in the `users` collection. So if you have many users, each with their own lists, only the lists of `user1` are queried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firestore query subcollections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573014/firestore-query-subcollections)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**The SDK now supports this**

Please see the other answers below...

**Old answer**

You can query on a subcollection as long as you know the document it belongs to. For example the following is a valid subcollection query:

```
const usersCollection = firestore.collection("users");
const adminDocument = usersCollection.doc("admin");
const adminsFollowersQuery = adminDocument.collection("followers").where("name", "==", "Arthur Dent");

adminsFollowersQuery.get().then((adminsFollowers) => {
  adminsFollowers.docs.forEach((adminFollower) => {
    console.log(adminFollower.get("name"));
  });
});
```

As you point out the following is NOT currently valid:

```
const allUserFollowersQuery = firestore.collection("users/{wildcard}/followers")
  .where("name", "==", "Arthur Dent");

adminsFollowersQuery.get().then((allUserFollowers) => {
  allUserFollowers.docs.forEach((follower) => {
    console.log(follower.get("name"));
  });
});
```

I think the documentation here is a little confusing but by "Querying across subcollections" they mean, you can query a specific subcollection, as above, but you cannot query general subcollections. At least not as a single action using the FireStore SDK.

Answer (score 8):

Firebase now supports [querying subcollections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) (as of May 2019).

You can do this

```
db.collectionGroup("lists").where("public", "==", true)
```

which will return matching `lists` documents for all users.

Comment: Can I get all the `lists` subcollections but not from **all** documents, but only if the document ID is in a documents ID list that I supply?

Comment: just do `query(collection(firestore, "collection", "specific_id", "sub-collection"))`