# Get a list of documents in a collection

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I'd like to get an array of all the documents that are in a collection.

Ie I have a file.struture like this

```
database.doc(`users/${user}/characters/characterA/data/${type}`)
```

I want to get a list of all the characters within the "characters" collections and I would really like to use the .doc() method to generate the random IDs for characters

Comment: There is currently no way to query subcollections across multiple documents. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573014/firestore-query-subcollections

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firestore query subcollections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573014/firestore-query-subcollections)