# Firestore: Get documents without parent document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm using Firebase Cloud Firestore and can't figure out how to access documents without knowing the specific path.  The database structure is `users/{user id}/favourites/{favourite id}`.  There are **no** fields in `users/{user id}` only subcollections.  Knowing the user id, i can get the favourites for the user, but I can't get a list of users to get everyone's favourites.  Here is the code I am trying (Java admin SDK):

```
db.collection("users").get().get()
```

which results in an empty `Iterable` with no `DocumentSnapshot`s.

How can I get a list of the most popular favourites?

**EDIT:** I've discovered I can get a list of users with no fields if I add a field.  Even if I delete it later, it still appears as a document in the collection.

**EDIT2:** I've discovered that I can create an empty document, so I'm just doing that for now.  As a one-off, I can get a list of all users from firebase auth and look up which ones have a favourites collection and just set those to empty documents.

Comment: You need to know the path.  There's no way to get there without knowing.

Comment: What you're trying to do is read/query across the sub-collections of multiple documents. As Doug says, this is not possible at the moment. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46573167/209103

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen that's not actually what I'm trying to do.  I know I can't do that so I'm just trying to get a list of users.  I have found that I can add [and remove!] a dummy field and it works.  I've edited my question.  Please consider unmarking this as a duplicate.

Comment: If you're never going to have any meaningful data in user documents, then perhaps you should revise your schema. How about just `favorites/{fav_id}` and save `user_id` as an additional field on the leaf documents? You can get favorites of a user by `favorites.whereEqualTo('user_id', 'bob')`.

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka thanks for your suggestion.  I understand the write rate to the same document is quite limited.  That's why i have chosen to use separate documents.

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka thanks again for your suggestion.  what i will do is have a collection `userFavourites` with automatic ids and contents as `{user: 'user', favourite: 'favourite'}`

Comment: @DougStevenson The Firebase Console somehow knows about subcollections, even with no parent document.

Comment: @DarkNeuron I had asked https://stackoverflow.com/users/5081766/bojeil (Firebase staff) about this somewhere, and even he doesn't know how the console does it.  Probably not something exposed by the Firebase public API.

Comment: Yeah I've concluded the same, its a private API sadly.

Comment: Thanks very much for this - went down a 2 hour hole trying to figure out why no documents were returned. This technique worked brilliantly. :-)