# Performance of Chaining Firebase Firestore Query and Document Snapshot Tasks

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an Android app that uses Firebase Firestore to store some data. Since [collection group queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573014/firestore-query-subcollections) are not yet supported in Firestore, in order to build some of the result sets that I need, I have to do a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Query) followed by multiple [DocumentReference.get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference.html#get()) calls to achieve the desired end result.

My implementation is as follows:

**PlaylistFacade.java**

```
public static Task<QuerySnapshot> GetPlaylistSubscriptionsByOwner(FirebaseFirestore db, @NonNull String ownerUserId)
{
    Query playlistRef = db.collection("playlistSubscriptions")
            .whereEqualTo("ownerId", ownerUserId);

    return playlistRef.get();
}

public static Task<DocumentSnapshot> GetPlaylist(FirebaseFirestore db, @NonNull String playlistId)
{
    return db.collection("playlists").document(playlistId).get();
}
```

**PlaylistActivity.java**

```
PlaylistFacade.GetPlaylistSubscriptionsByOwner(mFirestore, this.GetCurrentUser().getUid())
            .continueWithTask(new Continuation<QuerySnapshot, Task<List<Task<?>>>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<List<Task<?>>> then(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    List<Task<DocumentSnapshot>> tasks = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(DocumentSnapshot doc:task.getResult().getDocuments())
                    {
                        PlaylistSubscription ps = doc.toObject(PlaylistSubscription.class);
                        ps.setId(doc.getId());
                        tasks.add(PlaylistFacade.GetPlaylist(mFirestore, ps.getPlaylistId()));
                    }
                    return Tasks.whenAllComplete(tasks);

                }
            })
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<List<Task<?>>>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<List<Task<?>>> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        List<Task<?>> tasks = task.getResult();
                        List<Playlist> playLists = new ArrayList<>();
                        int errorCount = 0;
                        for(Task<?> docTask : tasks)
                        {
                            if(docTask.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                DocumentSnapshot ds = (DocumentSnapshot)docTask.getResult();
                                Playlist pl = ds.toObject(Playlist.class);
                                pl.setId(ds.getId());
                                playLists.add(pl);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Crashlytics.logException(docTask.getException());
                                errorCount++;
                            }
                        }

                        if(errorCount > 0)
                            Toast.makeText(PlaylistActivity.this, "Encountered " + errorCount + " errors.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(PlaylistActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Crashlytics.logException(task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(PlaylistActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

The above works just fine, but I'm curious if there may be a better way to do it.

My questions are as follows:

1. Is chaining the [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) objects using `List<>` the ideal approach? Am I giving up any potential performance by using this approach?
2. Will using the Task chain still allow me to take advantage of Firebase's ability to [pipeline requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786)?
3. Will my use of [Tasks.whenAllComplete()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks.html#whenAllComplete(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E...)) allow me to conditionally accept failure of some or all results, or does Firebase's pipelining cause errors to propagate across requests such that I should really just use `Tasks.whenAllSuccess()` and avoid the need check success of each individual request?
4. Response times of my implementation seem fine on small result sets. Am I likely to get better performance as my result set grows if I build my result set in a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) before returning it to my app instead?
5. At what complexity of Firestore actions should I really be using an Executor as demonstrated in the `DocSnippets.java` sample on the [deleteCollection(...)](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-android/blob/c584fed76616eeb7153363ecca84b1360703cd69/firestore/app/src/main/java/com/google/example/firestore/DocSnippets.java#L1038-L1070) function?
6. Would using a [Transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/Transaction) to bundle requests ever net me any performance gains? Performance implications of doing reads inside a transaction aren't discussed in [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions).
7. Any news of when *collection group queries* will be available in Firestore? In time for Google IO, perhaps?

Thank you for your time.

**Other helpful resources for those who end up here with similar questions:**

[Doug Stevenson's Firebase Blog Post on Task Wiring](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/09/become-a-firebase-taskmaster-part-3_29.html)