# AngularFire Firestore Nested Query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'm using AngularFire 2, a Firestore database and Angular5/6.
I want to search a string, nested in collections and documents and get the parent-document.

Let's say I want to search the message "Hello World!", which is nested in

```
rooms > roomA > messages > message1.msg
```

and then get back the name of the chatroom `roomA.name = "my chat room"`

Is that even possible? Because I don't know which room even contains the message "Hello World!". It can be roomA / roomB, so no defined document... Also: I don't know which message contains the "Hello World".

So the path would look like `rooms/*/messages/*.msg` ? But how can I do a query on a path like that?

```
let query = afs.collection('rooms', ref => ref.where('???', '==', 'Hello World!')).valueChanges();
```

[image]

Comment: Firestore queries are restricted to a single colleciton. If the messages for each room are in a subcollection of that room, you can't search for messages across rooms. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573014/firestore-query-subcollections

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like,

```
this.afs.collection('rooms', ref => ref .where(roomA.messages.message1,'==','Hello World!')).valueChanges()
```