# Firestore : request collections from different documents

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore database has the following architecture :

```
users :
    [user_id1] :
        list :
            [list_id1] :
                count : [int]
                title : [String]
                ...
            [list_id2]...
            [list_id3]...
    [user_id2]...
    [user_id3]...
```

I'm trying to query **all** the items contained in every ***list*** and order them by ***count***.

Is there a way to do this with **one or two** requests ? (using Transaction)

**PS:** I created another collection at the root of my Firestore database which contains [user_id] and [list_id] for every ***list*** of the database.

Comment: Sadly you cannot do this right now. Please take a look at this answer > https://stackoverflow.com/a/46573167/3479489

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Indeed it seems we can't do this after all, sad...