# Advance AngularFirestore2 Query

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Let say I have boards collections. Many users can participate in any board. So when every user participates I store user doc inside another collections 'participants'.

Now I want to show all the boards in which a particular user participate.

How to do that using angularfirestore?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is known as a collection group query, which is currently not possible on Cloud Firestore. See [Firestore query subcollections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573014/firestore-query-subcollections)

So with your current model you can efficiently look up the users of a board, but you cannot efficiently look up the boards for a user. To allow the latter, consider adding a collection of boards for each user in a structure like `/users/$uid/boards/$boardid`.

Alternatively you can add an array field `users` to the board document and use an `array-contains` to perform the query:

```
db.collection('boards').where('users', 'array-contains', uid)
```

Comment: The alternate option is suitable for my requirement. Thanks for your reply.