# collectionGroup() is not public. Cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to use `collectionGroup()` inside a `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` to query a subcollection on my `FirebaseFirestore` and I get an error saying:

> 'collectionGroup(java.lang.String)' is not public in
>   'com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore'. Cannot be accessed
>   from outside package

```
class WallHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private LinearLayout root, llp, image_layout;
        private RelativeLayout rlp;
        private TextView comment, tv_due, tv_pass;
        private Button btn_play;
        private SeekBar seekBar;
        private ImageView imageView[] = new ImageView[3];

        public WallHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            root = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_root);

            llp = root.findViewById(R.id.llp);
            rlp = root.findViewById(R.id.rlp);
            comment = root.findViewById(R.id.tv_cmt);
            image_layout = root.findViewById(R.id.img_layout);

            btn_play = llp.findViewById(R.id.btn_play);

            tv_due = rlp.findViewById(R.id.tv_due);
            tv_pass = rlp.findViewById(R.id.tv_pass);
            seekBar = rlp.findViewById(R.id.seek_bar);

            imageView[0] = image_layout.findViewById(R.id.img_1);
            imageView[1] = image_layout.findViewById(R.id.img_2);
            imageView[2] = image_layout.findViewById(R.id.img_3);
        }


        void setData(final Map<String, Object> post) {

            FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            final StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();


            //This is where i get the error
            //db.collectionGroup()
            //


            //This code wasn't working so i want to replace it with the code above
            db.collection("Post")
                    //.document(post.get("post_Id").toString())
                    .document("mnk2EqrVmm3upTFYL4eB")
                    .collection("Post_Images")
                    .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {

                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                final List<Bitmap> list = new ArrayList<>();
                                Toast.makeText(WallActivity.this, String.valueOf(task.getResult().size()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()){

                                }
                            } else {

                            }

                        }
                    });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add the code that you are using and indicate the exact line of code at which this error occurs.

Comment: i have added the code. The error i get is in the setData() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the following error:

> 'collectionGroup(java.lang.String)' is not public in 'com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore'. Cannot be accessed from outside package

Because in the earlier versions of Firestore, FirebaseFirestore's [collectionGroup(String collectionId)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html) method was defined with no modifier, which means that is only accessible within the same class and within the same package.

Since none of those two conditions is fulfilled, you could access that method outside the class or package. So it means that you are **not** using the latest version.

Starting with May 8th, 2019, the `collectionGroup(String collectionId)` is made public, so please your upgrade Firestore dependency to:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.0'
```

And you'll be able to use that method.

Comment: This doesn't work for sub collections. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573014/firestore-query-subcollections

Comment: Plus in the documentation collectionGroup() is public, See https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore.html#public-querycollectiongroupstring-collectionid

Comment: Well i moved all my subcollections to top level collections instead. thanks

Comment: Ok but it has nothing to do with your question. The error that you got was because you were using an old version for your Firebase Firestore dependency.

Comment: On Firestore website the latest api version is 18.2.0. when did they release 19.0.0

Comment: I don't know where you saw that, but [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) is the official documentation.  See, `com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:19.0.0`? Maybe in some other docs is not still updated but you can count on this link.