# Change nested sub-collections on CloudFunctions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need help with something.

I have 2 collections on my project, one is called **products** and another called **stores**.

One product can belong to many stores, so to make the app more “performatic”, I’m duplicating the selected product information into a sub-collection of **stores**, in this case **stores > products**.

My idea is to create a cloud-function that will watch for any updates on any product and then reflect those changes on the **stores > products** sub-collection by updating the values.

I’m already saving it with the same ID. So for example, the productID 1 under the `products` collection will have the same id under the **stores > products** sub-collection.

My question is, how can I query only the **products** sub-collection? Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

It depends what do you exactly want to query.

If you want to query only **ONE** specific product document within the products sub-collection of **ONE** given store document you would do as follows:

```
var docRef = db.collection("stores").doc(storeId).collection("products").doc(productId)

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

---

If you want to query the products sub-collection of **ONE** given store (getting all the products docs within this sub-collection) you would do as follows:

```
db.collection("stores").doc(storeId).collection("products").get()
  .then(function(querySnapshot) {
     //....
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
     //....
  });
```

---

If you want to query the products sub-collections of **ALL** the stores, you would use a [Collection Group Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?authuser=0#collection-group-query), as follows:

```
var productsCollGroup = db.collectionGroup('products');

productsCollGroup.get()
.then(function (querySnapshot) {
     //....
})
.catch(function(error) {
     //....
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks. If I run the `collectionGroup` wouldn't that also catch the main **Products** collection? Would that be the case for me to change the name of that sub-collections?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the thread on this link [1], specifically to your question you can check this answer [2].

For example they mention have an array of documents and they provide the answer of how to search for an specific document within a collection.

[1] [Firestore query subcollections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573014/firestore-query-subcollections)

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/a/46585748/9054282