# Referencing a subcollection / document in a *ngFor loop

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

In my Cloud Firestore database, my top collection is called `meters`, all the documents have custom numeric ids like `12345`, and each document has a subcollection called `meterdata` and all the document ids for each of those are dates like `2019-12-14`.

In my `meter-list.component.ts` I have

```
export class MeterListComponent implements OnInit {

 meters: Observable<any[]>;

 constructor(db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.meters = db.collection(('meters'), ref=> ref.where("usagetoday", ">", 0)).valueChanges();
  }
```

and in my `meter-list.component.html` I have a loop

```
<div *ngFor="let meter of meters | async">
{{meter.id}}
{{meter.address}}
{{meter.usagetoday}}
{{meter.lastupdated}}
</div>
```

which returns a list of all the meters, with the address and a field which is updated daily with the latest usage.

I would like to be able to reference in the `meter-list.component.html` a calculated field called `morning` on each day's `meterdata` document, but I'm not sure how to reference the subdocument.

I know that it is not `{{meter[meter.id].['meterdata'][meter.lastupdated].morning}}`.

I also tried to include a line in the `meter-list.component.ts` that would look like `this.meterdata = db.collection('meters').doc(this.meters.id).collection('meterdata').doc(this.meters.lastupdated).valueChanges();` which would allow me to call `*ngIf = "meterdata | async as meterdata"` inside the `*ngFor` loop and include `{{ meterdata.morning }}`, but that obviously doesn't work either.

I'd really appreciate any push in the right direction.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you paste the structure of the `meters` json in the question?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is this: "meters" - "12345" - "meterdata" - "2019-12-14". The way I would directly refer to this would be collection('meters').doc('12345').collection('meterdata').doc('2019-12-14')

Comment: Err, not really. What would `meter` look after the constructor is invoked?

Comment: you mean this? (this is the `doc.data()` of a `meter`.) ```{
  address: '123 Dumbledore Dr',
  city: 'Beverly Hills',
  day: 'tuesday',
  hourlyarray: [
    251, 36,  26,  24, 119,  47,   8,
     18, 32,  76, 206,  72,  72,  99,
     50, 94, 144,  64, 155, 140, 166,
     94, 90,  68
  ],
  lastupdated: '2019-12-31',
  meter: '12345',
  perunit: 33.61,
  state: 'CA',
  units: 64,
  zipcode: '90210'
}```

Comment: Yes. Now with this json what is it that you are trying to display?

Comment: I'm using Cloud Firestore. These are only the fields on this particular document. This document has a subcollection called `meterdata` and that subcollection has a document called `2019-12-14` whose json looks like ```{
  date: '2019-12-14',
  day: 'saturday',
  earlymorning: 612,
  evening: 1284,
  hourlyarray: [
    165,  76,  34, 311,  26,  88,
    291, 333, 413, 498, 323, 153,
    375, 250, 289, 284, 259, 247,
    300, 194, 297, 327, 140, 240
  ],
  meter: '12345',
  midday: 1390,
  morning: 1623,
  night: 1004,
  perunit: 140.78,
  units: 64,
  usage: 5913
}
```

Comment: And I would like to display the `earlymorning` from that document.

Comment: Well I'm not too sure about cloud firestore, but can't you store the required json into a variable and then work with that?

Comment: I theoretically can. The problem is that I'm trying to access other information as well, and this was the easiest possible way to pose the question to be understandable. And once I start storing all the relevant fields on the original document it gets to be rather unwieldy.

Comment: Hmm, that's true also. I wish you luck then!

Comment: I think you can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573014/firestore-query-subcollections