# Unable to get nested list of data from Firebase Firestore (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

My database structure looks like this:

[image]

I have to take all dNames and print it.

```
const db = firebase.firestore();

db.collection('map-data').doc('driver').get().then((snapshot) => {
  snapshot.docs.forEach(doc=> { console.log(doc.data()['dName']) })
});
```

Comment: Please share the code that you have tried.

Comment: tried this       const db =firebase.firestore();
          
         db.collection('map-data').doc('driver').get().then((snapshot)=>{
          snapshot.docs.forEach(doc=>{
           console.log(doc.data()['dName']);
           // console.log(doc);
          })
          
         });

Comment: What do you mean by *"take all list of dNames"* (seems incomprehensible)?

Comment: i apologise for that. I have to take all dNames and put in one array to display it

Comment: You have another collection inside `driver`, so how could you directly access the `dName` ?

Comment: Have a look at this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore query subcollections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46573014/firestore-query-subcollections)